# TS2786 'Component' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-dom, tsx

I have a React Typescript application that won't compile. Many components have a render method that is typed to return `React.ReactNode` or `React.ReactElement`. On compile, many errors similar to the following are reported:

```
TS2786: 'MessagesWidget' cannot be used as a JSX component.
 Its instance type 'MessagesWidget' is not a valid JSX element.
 The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
 Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/node/app/node_modules/@types/react-calendar/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
```

Why is the compiler expecting `ReactNode` as defined by the types bundled with `react-calendar`? I do have `@types/react-dom` installed as a dev dependency.

Other information that might be relevant:

1. This project was compiling until a couple of days ago and there were no code changes when the compile started failing, so I suspect that a package update triggered this (even if that's not the root cause). The only dependencies that were updated in the time window when the compile started failing were `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom`. Rolling these packages back to an older version did not fix the issue, however.
2. Changing my components render methods to return `JSX.Element` removes the compiler error, but there are third party components in the application where this is not possible.

Comment: `React.ReactNode` is definitely the correct return type for the `render` method of react components, so this is pretty strange. But without [a minimal example,](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I'm not sure we can be of much help.

Comment: I had the exact same issue pop up today, except my import is from `react-dom` or `react-transition-group`. There's definitely something wrong with the types package. I just added `@ts-ignore` in the meantime.

Comment: We are seeing this on our projects. I'll try hard fixing @types to older version.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I have a solution, it seems that there are a ton of breaking changes in the 18.0.1 type definitions.

Like you, I could not solve it by rolling back to earlier versions, but investigation lead me to discover that this was because 'react-router' among others was bringing in the '18.0.1' version.

to get around this, I added the following to my package.json

```
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.14"
  },
```

Then I cleared my node-modules, and my package cache and then re-ran yarn to pull fresh packages.

The resolutions section is for yarn (which I use). and I think you can use 'overrides' instead of 'resolutions' if you are using NPM.

npm version should >= 8
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

and delete package-lock.json before npm i.

Comment: I'm on yarn workspace monorepo with lerna. add it in root package.json
"resolutions": {
    "**/@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "**/@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8"
  }
works for me.

from: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/503fr9

Comment: Sadly not working for me

Comment: still not working

Comment: Are you using yarn or npm?  it might be another package that is causing the issue.

Comment: This was accurate earlier this year, but is no longer necessary. This issue with the type defs has long since been fixed.

Answer (score 44):

[**Error TS2786**](https://typescript.tv/errors/#TS2786) often comes from a mismatch in `@types/react`.

When you have libraries that are dependent on a specific version of `@types/react` (i.e. v17.0.47) and you have other libraries working with a different major version of `@types/react` (i.e. v18.0.14), then this can cause compatibility issues when using `React.ReactNode` or `JSX.Element`. The type `JSX.Element` is usually returned by a React Function Component.

You can solve the problem by streamlining your dependencies on `@types/react`, so that these follow the same major version. You can find all libraries depending on `@types/react` in your project by executing `npm explain @types/react` (when a `package-lock.json` file is present) or `yarn why @types/react` (when a `yarn.lock` file is present).

In your specific case there seems to be a dependency from `@types/react-calendar` to `@types/react`. Your problem seems to be that there are other dependencies in your project using a different version of `@types/react`. Maybe you even have a direct dependency on `@types/react` where the exact version number is different from the `@types/react` version required by `@types/react-calendar`.

[Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eeXDwuAjSFo) that shows how to inspect the applied version of `@types/react` in your own project.

Comment: Mismatch in `react` and `@types/react` versions it is. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't explain how to fix the issue, which would be to actually run `npm dedupe`

Comment: You could use `npm dedupe` or you could use `resolutions` to force a resolution if there's a hard dependency coming in from an over-zealous package.json.

Comment: When using `yarn` then the `dedupe` functionality is already applied: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/dedupe - If this doesn't help, you would have to inspect where the typings come from manually by using `yarn why` or `npm explain`.

Comment: I had to update the `@types/react` version in the `resolutions` block.

Answer (score 9):

This can occur when returning `children`:

```js
export const Component = ({ children }) => {
    //...do stuff
    return children
}
```

To fix, wrap in a fragment:

```js
return <>{children}</>
```

I believe this is because `children` may be an array of elements and we are only allowed to return a single element. The usual message for this kind of error is:

`JSX expressions must have one parent element.`

Answer (score 8):

If there's a `yarn` user wandering around; who had this issue after doing a react/react-native version upgrade recently; just **delete** the existing `yarn.lock` file & the `node_modules` folder and run `yarn install` again is what worked for me. :)

Comment: This worked for me for react web app, deleted node_modules and yarn.lock and re-installed everything and all the warnings were resolved

Answer (score 6):

After updating React Native from 0.66.3 to 0.70.6, I faced the same issue. I solved the problem by changing the "resolutions" in the package.json

```
"resolutions": {
    // "@types/react": "^17" remove this
    "@types/react": "^18.0.8" //adding this
},
```

After changing this, remove node_modules directory and run `npm i` or `yarn`.

Answer (score 4):

This issue comes with mismatch in @types/react versions [TS2786](https://typescript.tv/errors/#TS2786)

Fix it with [npm dedupe](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-dedupe) or [yarn dedupe](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/dedupe)

Comment: It shows me this: error The dedupe command isn't necessary. `yarn install` will already dedupe

Comment: Ok, Try adding `@types/react` resolutions in package.json 
`
"resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.34"
  }
`

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers above solved my case for the same typescript error TS2786
how I get it work is update tsconfig.json

from

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "preserveSymlinks": true,
    ...
```

to

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "preserveSymlinks": false,
    ...
```

or just simply remove it

Comment: For me, setting to to `true` actually fixed the error. There's an github issue similar to this: https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/3671

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't add @types/react, please add it first by:

```
yarn add --dev @types/react
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using some older React based libraries, maybe there is a mismatch in your React types.
Try adding this to your tsconfig.json ("compilerOptions"):

```
"paths": {
    "react": [ "./node_modules/@types/react" ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the latest version of react and react-dom in package.json and run below command to re-install react and react-dom

Here , while posting this answer, latest version of react and react-dom is 18.

Steps-

1. Remove **package-lock.json** file of your proect
2. Open **package.json** of your project.
3. replace react and react-dom version

> ```
> "@types/react": "^18",
>
> "@types/react-dom": "^18"
> ```

4.Run command

> npm install --save-dev @types/react @types/react-dom

Done. It resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by changing ``jsx`: 'react'` in tsconfig.json into `jsx`:`react-jsx`

Answer (score 1):

I will tell about the react-native project.
All these answers didn't help me.
But I found out the reason for this issue in my project.
I forgot to fill "types" parameter in tsconfig.json.

Adding

```
"types": ["react-native", "jest"]
```

helped me.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The problem arose after updating to the latest version (18) of `@types/react`. Many React libraries depend on @types/react with a wildcard "*", causing them to automatically upgrade to version 18 when installing modules or creating builds. This can lead to compatibility issues if the code isn't updated to support version 18.

Identifying the issue was tricky because it might appear that nothing changed in the `package.json` file, but the problem lies in the automatic upgrade to `@types/react` version 18 due to the wildcard dependency.

To resolve this until the packages are updated, you can force the use of the older version of `@types/react`. If you're using Yarn, you can add this to your `package.json`:

```
"resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.26"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because `react-route` v18 does not support `react-virtualized` and it should be downgraded.

So the simple way is to downgrade your route as below:

```
"@types/react": "17.0.0",
"@types/react-dom": "17.0.0"
```

Then, your app should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue about this error. I add the below code to my package.json file and got resolved.

```
"resolutions": {
  "@types/react": "17.0.2",
  "@types/react-dom": "17.0.2",
  "graphql": "^16.5.0"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you previously had a resolution for react 17:

```
"resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0"
 },
```

it generates an entry in package-lock/yarn lock that won't be removed when you update. So you need to remove this resolution and the yarn lock entry.
It looks like this:

```
"@types/react@*", "@types/react@17.0.21", "@types/react@^17":
  version "17.0.21"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types/react/-/react-17.0.21.tgz#069c43177cd419afaab5ce26bb4e9056549f7ea6"
  integrity something
  dependencies:
    "@types/prop-types" "*"
    "@types/scheduler" "*"
    csstype "^3.0.2"
```

Removing both and running install again should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

For me, I mistakenly added async to the react component. Removing it and creating my async function inside the react component fixes mine.

```
export async const Component = () => {
   
}
```

**to**

```
export const Component = () => {
    const asyncFunction = async () => {
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that TypeScript is having trouble with async components, expecting JSX but not recognizing Promise. To address this, some are type casting the component and exporting the casted version. One workaround is to use the @ts-expect-error directive to ignore TypeScript errors related to async components temporarily. However, once TypeScript updates its types, this directive might become unnecessary. The fix for this issue could potentially be included in the next TypeScript plugin update.

```
<div>
  {/* @ts-expect-error Server Component */}
  other codes ... 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happened to me with a fresh `react-native` project. This is why this was so confusing. The fix in my case was really, I had to re-install `@types/react` to use the latest version. I'm not sure why the `npx react-native@latest init` command did not use the latest version of those types.

```bash
yarn add --dev @types/react
```

Answer (score -1):

my one got solved after I fixed the RETURN statement of my child component

I had in there:

```
return; <form></form>
```

changed to:

```
return (<form></form>)
```