# Some components from 3rd party packages cannot use in React component tree

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React project with version `17.0.2` and `notistack@2.0.5`. Now when I try to import the snackbar provider and try to use it as,

```
import { SnackbarProvider } from 'notistack';

return <SnackbarProvider maxSnack={3}>
  <AppRouter />
</SnackbarProvider>
```

its throw the following error,

```
'SnackbarProvider' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'SnackbarProvider' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/madukadilshan/Desktop/projects/sma-web/node_modules/@sm/common-ui/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2786)
```

Same issue happens with the `import PerfectScrollbar from 'react-perfect-scrollbar';`

package versions

- react: `17.0.2`
- notistack: `2.0.5`
- react-perfect-scrollbar: `^1.5.8`
- react version in common package: `17.0.2`

---

It worked perfectly till yesterday. Today I installed a custom component package I made. Initially I used React 18 in the common ui package. I though maybe the issue is because of that. Tried to downgrade the react version in the common package to v17 and re install the package again. ( Also tried removing node_modules completely and reinstall all ) but still the error remain.

Does anyone know how can I fix this issue ? Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71831601/) as well but didn't worked.

---

UPDATE

After I changed the react v18 to v17 in my common package, now its shows a same error but with different 3rd party package that uses react in the common ui.

What I have tried so far,

**Using `any` type** ( Definitely not what i want to do )

```
import { SnackbarProvider } from 'notistack';
const SnackbarProviderX: any = SnackbarProvider;

return <SnackbarProviderX></SnackbarProviderX>
```

**Upgrade react version in main project**

upgrade the React v17 -> v18 in main project so that it matches with the react version in common package which is v18. Doing this fixed the issue but introduced the same error with `@mui` package. Its never ends fixing one introduce another one.

So, is there any proper way to ignore this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

If you read carefully the npm package or git you can find this :

```
If you're using Material-UI version 4.x.x or lower, download a compatible version of notistack using:

npm install notistack@latest-mui-v4
yarn add notistack@latest-mui-v4
```

I got the same trouble earlier this month, I know the struggle

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the issue first appeared when I install my custom ui package which does not use MUI.  When I uninstall the package, the main project start working again.

Comment: The custom package is uses React Native components, then I use `react-native-web` to use them on web. That part is okay. Its' working on development env.  Issue happens when  the `@types/react` inside `@types/react-native` is v18 no matter old version of `@types/react-native` i install.

Comment: The issue with MUI happens when I try to upgrade the react version of main project, so it matches with the version of `@types/react` (v18) inside `@types/react-native` in my common package. When I do this MUI start to throw same issues with its components. I'm using v5 Mui

Comment: Maybe you already tried it but I saw on this issue: https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack/issues/485 that you can put ` "@types/react": "18.0.8",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.3"` to solve this issue

Comment: I also saw that you need to put a special flag to install @mui since it's not working with react 18 for now, they are talking about it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71713111/mui-installation-doesnt-work-with-react-18

Comment: I tried the `"resolution"` one already. didn't worked. I'll try the the other link you sent. Thanks for that :)