# 'TouchableOpacity' cannot be used as a JSX component. 'View' is not a valid JSX element

Tags: react-native, components, jsx, package.json

'TouchableOpacity' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its instance type 'TouchableOpacity' is not a valid JSX element.
The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'import("/Users/sanjeevkumar/React/help_idea_update/mypatapp-v2-update/node_modules/@types/react-native/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'React.ReactNode'.

[image]

why this is giving error message i already do this

```
"resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "graphql": "^16.5.0"
  },
```

and run yarn install

Comment: Please share your full code.

Comment: Make sure import it from react-native instead of react-native-gesture-handler.         Like ***import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native***

Comment: Find the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71831601/ts2786-component-cannot-be-used-as-a-jsx-component

Answer (score 1):

The warning is coming from typescript.

Update the following

```
"@types/react": "17.0.14",
```

For "@types/react-native", update to same version as the react-native and install again.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is coming from typescript.

Update the "@types/react" to save version as the react version.

Same for @types/react-dom in your de dependencies

Answer (score 0):

My `react` package version was `16.13.1` and installing `@types/react@16` fixed the issue for me .

Basically `react` & `@types/react` packages versions should match .